# Removing Items from Gridview and refreshing the gridview without redirecting to the same Page.(Windows Phone 8.1 Xaml)

Tags: gridview, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, itemtemplate, flyout

I have a gridview with a Usercontrol as its itemtemplate.

In the Usercontrol I have a flyout attached to it using which the user can choose to delete the entry. After deletion how do I remove the entry/Update the gridview  without redirecting to the samePage and removing the backstack entry?

Please note that I am deleting/modifying the itemssource in the usercontrol's codebehind buttonclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your itemssource implements *INotifyCollectionChanged*, it will automatically reflrect Addition ans Removals in the GridView.

You can use *ObservableCollection* as ItemsSource, it already implements it.

And of course you can just remove the items directly using GridView.Items.Remove (or RemoveAt).

Comment: Thanks :) Got it working but forgot to update the answer here :)